# Java Swing Mouse Input not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a game where it requires mouse Input, I did it the same way I do Key Input by making a Mouse class that extends MouseAdapter. When tested it by clicking in the window, it did nothing. The code is provided below. Any help appreciated.

Main Class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class TopDownShooter {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
    frame.setSize(1360,680);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.add(new GameFrame());
    frame.setVisible(true);


   }

}
```

MouseAdapt Class

```
 import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 public class MouseAdapt extends MouseAdapter {

   public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
   {
    System.out.print("Mouse Clicked");

   }
}
```

GameFrame Class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;      
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;       
import javax.swing.*;
public class GameFrame extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

Timer mainTimer;
public GameFrame()
{
    setFocusable(true)
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapt());
    mainTimer = new Timer(10,this);
    mainTimer.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MouseClicked` does not exist as part of the `MouseListener` interface

You should ALWAYS use the `@Override` annotation when you think you're overriding a method, as it will generate a compile time error if there is a problem (like a typo)

For example...

```
public class MouseAdapt extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}
```

will fail, but...

```
public class MouseAdapt extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}
```

will compile

Remember, Java is case sensitive, it's very easy to make these kind of un-obvious mistakes.

You should also have a look at [How to write a mouse listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) in the future, to make sure you've implemented the functionality correctly when ever you have problems like this